# How should I apply CSS selectors on a parsed HTML like this?

Tags: c#, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply CSS selectors on HTML sources where each DOM element is parsed like this:

```
Destination URL, Text, (DOM Path in format \TagName, ClassName, Id, ChildRank)
```

For example:

```
\TagName=A&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=LI&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=UL&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=header-wrap&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=header-classified&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=header-container&Id=&ChildRank=3
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=main-container&Id=&ChildRank=1
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=ody-custom%20cobrand&Id=&ChildRank=2
\TagName=DIV&ClassName=ody-skin&Id=&ChildRank=10
\TagName=CENTER&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=2
\TagName=BODY&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=3
\TagName=HTML&ClassName=&Id=&ChildRank=0
```

I'd like to know is there an easy way to do this in C#, say if I have a list of CSS selectors and I want to see whether there is a CSS selector that can actually select a DOM element in the DOM elements?

Sorry the question might seem unclear.

Comment: It sounds like you need to parse the CSS yourself and see if anything matches your DOM paths.  I don't know of built in way of doing that...

Comment: Closest built-in thing might be to parse the HTML into an XML tree, and then use XPath on the tree

Comment: @onemancat: Thanks, is there an easy way to parse the abovementioned HTML structure into XML then?